# unable to unserialize a string in php

Tags: php, serialization

Can any one tell me what is the problem with the following code? I am getting boolean false when unserializing this string:

```
a:3:{s:10:"Subscriber";O:14:"SubscriberType":8:{s:14:"organizationid";s:3:"omm";s:5:"jobid";s:13:"4f27d819d9fd2";s:8:"sequence";s:8:"42781971";s:20:"SubscriberTypedate";s:10:"2012-01-31";s:20:"SubscriberTypetime";s:8:"04:01:29";s:9:"timestamp";s:19:"2012-01-31T04:01:29";s:20:"SubscriberTypecert";s:46:"omm^4f27d819d9fd2^42781971^2012-01-31T04:01:29";s:11:"certificate";s:32:"ab673e29e0eb69a62b39781cdbec6368";}s:8:"Activity";O:12:"ActivityType":6:{s:5:"title";s:6:"ethics";s:8:"provider";s:21:"O'Melveny & Myers LLP";s:6:"format";s:2:"11";s:10:"completion";s:10:"2012-01-12";s:11:"description";s:35:"some's : test description here";s:7:"credits";s:17:"some credits here";}s:4:"Code";s:8:"SMH10634";}
```

I am using following code to serialize the data:

```
$stype = new SubscriberType($data1['OrgID'],$data1['OrgKey']);
$atype = new ActivityType($rdata['Title'],$data1['Provider'],$rdata['Format'],$rdata['Completion'],$rdata['Description'],$rdata['Credits']);
$repData = htmlentities(serialize(array("Subscriber"=>$stype,"Activity"=>$atype,"Code"=>$data2['ClientCode'])),ENT_QUOTES);
$sql = "insert into table values(compress('$repData'))";
```

And the following code to unserialize it.

```
$sql = "select uncompress(RepData) as RData from table";
$rData = unserialize(html_entity_decode($data['RData']));
```

Comment: What's the code you use to unserialize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect you just use `serialize()` and `unserialize()`.

When i run it I receive `Error at offset 169 of 700 bytes`. You should encode special charachters and escape quotes. Here is how -> http://davidsword.ca/unserialize-error-at-offset/

Comment: just solved the issue, instead of using htmlentities and html_entity_decode functions, i used addslashes and stripslashes functions.

Comment: Your link is expired, can you add the explanation to your answer?

Comment: wow that was a long time ago... But I think it was that you should use htmlspecialchars() and addeslashes() to clean up before using serialize()